# How do I use RestSharp to POST a login and password to an API?

Tags: c#, rest, post, cookies, httprequest

I'm trying to write a C# application that will call an api for Pacer.gov.  First thing I need to do it get a cookie to pass with my request.  I'm using Chrome's Postman app to try to generate a POST request.  Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

The instructions I got from Pacer.gov to get the authentication token are

> For credentials, you can POST username(loginid) and password(passwd) to the authentication service here https://pacer.login.uscourts.gov/cgi-bin/check-pacer-passwd.pl 
>   This will issue you a PacerSession cookie.

Here are some ways I tried:
(I’m just showing @@@@@ as the login and ***** as the password, but I used the actual login and password when I tried it)

- Including username and password in the URL

  ```
  var client = new RestClient("https://pacer.login.uscourts.gov/cgi-in/check-pacer-passwd.pl?loginid=@@@@@&passwd=*****");
  var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
  request.AddHeader("postman-token", "a5bd0d9c-85f5-4ed6-6ad8-ac06e553f5db");
  request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
  IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
  ```

  o   Received HTML page saying “Access to PACER requires a valid account id and password.  “
- Including username and password in the header

  ```
  var client = new RestClient("https://pacer.login.uscourts.gov/cgi-bin/check-pacer-passwd.pl");
  var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
  request.AddHeader("postman-token", "add9dedf-10bf-eab4-428a-134c0e8a1783");
  request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
  request.AddHeader("passwd", "*****");
  request.AddHeader("loginid", "@@@@@");
  IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
  ```

  o   Received HTML page saying “Access to PACER requires a valid account id and password.  “
- Including username and password in the body as form data

  ```
  var client = new RestClient("https://pacer.login.uscourts.gov/cgi-bin/check-pacer-passwd.pl");
  var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
  request.AddHeader("postman-token", "454a8ebd-b2b4-3db2-0c5c-c48e2964c671");
  request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
  request.AddHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=---011000010111000001101001");
  request.AddParameter("multipart/form-data; boundary=---011000010111000001101001", "-----011000010111000001101001\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"loginid\"\r\n\r\n@@@@@\r\n-----011000010111000001101001\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data;          name=\"passwd\"\r\n\r\n*****\r\n-----011000010111000001101001--", ParameterType.RequestBody);
  IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
  ```

  o   Received message “Could not get any response”
- Typing URL into Chrome with the username and password

  ```
  https://pacer.login.uscourts.gov/cgi-bin/check-pacer-passwd.pl?loginid=@@@@@&passwd=*****
  ```

  o   Received error “This site can’t be reached”

UPDATE - 5-31-16

I've made several more attempts, but am still not getting the cookie back.  I tried this code:

```
        var client = new RestClient("https://pacer.login.uscourts.gov");

        var request = new RestRequest("/cgi-bin/check-pacer-passwd.pl", Method.POST);
        request.AddParameter("loginid", "@@@@@");
        request.AddParameter("passwd", "*****");

        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

When I look at the response, there is one cookie called JESSIONID which appears just to be a generic browser session ID, not the authentication code I'm expecting:

[image]

I'm not exactly sure what to expect from the response, but I know that a "NextGenCSO cookie" was mentioned in one of the e-mails from Pacer.  If I login through the web browser and look at the cookies, I see a NextGenCSO cookie; I'm guessing I should be seeing something similar in the response from the API call:

[image]

UPDATE - 6-3-16

Thanks to help from @jonathon-reinhart, I was able to get the authentication cookie working with this code:

```
// Authentication
        var client = new RestClient("https://pacer.login.uscourts.gov");

        client.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
        var request = new RestRequest("/cgi-bin/check-pacer-passwd.pl", Method.POST);
        request.AddParameter("loginid", "@@@@@");
        request.AddParameter("passwd", "*****");

        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

        var PacerSession = "";

        foreach (RestResponseCookie cookie in response.Cookies)
        {
            if (cookie.Name == "PacerSession")
            {
                PacerSession = cookie.Value;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not correctly POSTing as the directions indicate.

Putting this:

```
https://pacer.login.uscourts.gov/cgi-bin/check-pacer-passwd.pl?loginid=@@@@@&passwd=*****
```

into the address bar is not a POST. That's a GET with query string parameters.

See the [RestSharp homepage](http://restsharp.org/) for an example on how to POST:

```
var request = new RestRequest("resource/{id}", Method.POST);
request.AddParameter("name", "value"); // adds to POST or URL querystring based on Method
```

You want to include `loginid` and `passwd` as data ("parameters" as RestSharp calls them), *not* has headers.

So you should be instead doing something like this:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://pacer.login.uscourts.gov");

var request = new RestRequest("/cgi-bin/check-pacer-passwd.pl", Method.POST);
request.AddParameter("loginid", "@@@@");
request.AddParameter("passwd", "****");

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  This is what I was trying to do in Postman, but for some reason it added the parameters as query strings.  I tried your code (with the correct login/password, of course) and received this response: "The requested URL /cgi-in/check-pacer-passwd.pl was not found on this server."  Any suggestions on how to fix the code?

Comment: @boilers222 Your original code had a typo (`cgi-in` instead of `cgi-bin`), which I copy and pasted. I've corrected the code in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for helping.  Your code runs without errors, but I'm not getting the cookie I'm expecting as a response.  I updated the original case with the response I'm getting.  I suspect that there is something missing I'm going to have to get from Pacer, but they've been unresponsive.   Could you take a look at what I'm getting as my response and what I'd expect to get back and offer any suggestions?  Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I was able to get this working.  i updated my question if you want to see it.  Now that I have the authentication cookie, I'm working on making the actual request and having trouble with it.  I decided to make it a new case.  Would you mind taking a look at it and seeing what you think?  The cookie seems to be working, but I'm not getting the return file I was expecting. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37620997/how-do-i-make-a-case-request-from-the-pacer-gov-api