# How do I make a case request from the Pacer.gov API?

Tags: c#, rest, post, httpresponse, restsharp

I am trying to make a request to an API called Pacer.gov.  I'm expecting a file to be returned, but I'm not getting it.  Can someone help me with what I'm missing?

So my C# Rest call looks like this:

(The variable PacerSession is the authentication cookie I got (with help from @jonathon-reinhart); read more about that here: [How do I use RestSharp to POST a login and password to an API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37491868/how-do-i-use-restsharp-to-post-a-login-and-password-to-an-api))

```
            var client = new RestClient("https://pcl.uscourts.gov/dquery");

        client.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
        //var request = new RestRequest("/dquery", Method.POST);
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddParameter("download", "1");
        request.AddParameter("dl_fmt", "xml");
        request.AddParameter("party", "Moncrief");

        request.AddHeader("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36");
        request.AddHeader("content-type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
        request.AddHeader("accept", "*/*");
        request.AddHeader("accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate, sdch");
        request.AddHeader("accept-language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
        request.AddHeader("cookie", "PacerSession=" + PacerSession);

        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

If I just type the URL https://pcl.uscourts.gov/dquery?download=1&dl_fmt=xml&party=Moncrief into Chrome, I get back an XML file.  When I look at the IRestResponse, I don't see anything that looks like a file.  Is there something wrong with my request or am I getting the file back and just need to know how to retrieve it?

Here's part of the file I get back if I use the URL directly in the browser:

[image]

Here's what I see in VS when I debug it and look at the IRestResponse variable:

[image]

UPDATE - 6/3/16

Received this response from Pacer tech support:

> In the Advanced REST Client, you will see a HTTP 302 response (a redirect to another page).  In a normal browser, the redirect is automatically followed without the user seeing anything (even on the URL in the browser). 
>   The ARC does not automatically follow that redirect to the target page. 
>   You can see in the header of the response the target URL that has the results.
>   If you manually cut and paste this URL to the ARC as a HTTP GET request, you will get the XML results. I have never used C#, but there is usually a property associated with web clients that will force the client to follow the redirect.

I tried adding this:

```
client.FollowRedirects = true;
```

but I'm still not seeing an xml file when I debug this code:

```
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

[image]

How do I get the file?  Is there something I have to do to get the file from the URL it's being redirected to?

Comment: From your debugger screenshot, the content type is _not_ xml. It's a webpage. Specifically, the Pacer login page. Even more specifically the pacer login page with a redirect to the search page. (Look at the `ContentType` property, and the `ResponseUri` property)

Comment: Thanks for responding @theB.  From what I got from Pacer tech support, it sounds like the request is being redirected. I tried turning the FollowRedirects option on, but I'm still not seeing the xml file.  How do I get the file from this redirected page?  I updated my original question with the information from Pacer.

Answer (score 0):

There's one major problem with your code. You're only carrying *one* of the three cookies that `checp-pacer-passwd.pl` returns.  You need to preserve all three. The following code is a possible implementation of this, with some notes afterwards.

```
public class PacerClient
{
    private CookieContainer m_Cookies = new CookieContainer();
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public PacerClient(string username, string password)
    {
        this.Username = username;
        this.Password = password;
    }
    public void Connect()
    {
        var client = new RestClient("https://pacer.login.uscourts.gov");
        client.CookieContainer = this.m_Cookies;
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest("/cgi-bin/check-pacer-passwd.pl", Method.POST);
        request.AddParameter("loginid", this.Username);
        request.AddParameter("passwd", this.Password);

        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

        if (response.Cookies.Count < 1)
        {
            throw new WebException("No cookies returned.");
        }
    }
    public XmlDocument SearchParty(string partyName)
    {
        string requestUri = $"/dquery?download=1&dl_fmt=xml&party={partyName}";

        var client = new RestClient("https://pcl.uscourts.gov");
        client.CookieContainer = this.m_Cookies;

        var request = new RestRequest(requestUri);

        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(response.Content))
        {
            XmlDocument result = new XmlDocument();
            result.LoadXml(response.Content);
            return result;
        }
        else return null;
    }
}
```

It's easiest to just keep a hold of the `CookieContainer` throughout the entire time you're working with Pacer. I wrapped the functionality into a class, just to make it a little easier to package up with this answer, but you can implement it however you want. I didn't put in any real error checking, so you probably want to check that `response.ResponseUri` is actually the search page and not the logon page, and that the content is actually well-formed XML.

I've tested this using my own Pacer account, like so:

```
PacerClient client = new PacerClient(Username, Password);
client.Connect();
var document = client.SearchParty("Moncrief");
```